# Woocommerce - Display single product attribute(s) with shortcodes in Frontend

Tags: php, woocommerce, attributes

i've read many Q/A's here during the last few days, but unfortunately none of them solved my issue.

I'm trying to fetch product attributes and display them on the frontend with a shortcode. I have managed to display ALL available attributes and display them in a list, but i need to select only one or two of them in different locations (thats why using shortcodes). For example like [shortcode_attribute name="brand"].

Any help is highly appreciated!

my code so far:

```
function tutsplus_list_attributes( $product ) {

global $product;
global $post;

$attributes = $product->get_attributes();

if ( ! $attributes ) {

return;

}

foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ) {

// Get the taxonomy.
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $product->id, $attribute[ 'name' ], 'all' );
$taxonomy = $terms[ 0 ]->taxonomy;

// Get the taxonomy object.
$taxonomy_object = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy );

// Get the attribute label.
$attribute_label = $taxonomy_object->labels->name;

// Display the label followed by a clickable list of terms.
echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, $attribute[ 'name' ] , '<div><li class="bullet-arrow">' . $attribute_label . ': ' , ', ', '</li></div>' );

}

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_end', 'tutsplus_list_attributes' );
add_shortcode('display_attributes', 'tutsplus_list_attributes');
```

Comment: What's the result of the shortcode you are using? Are you trying to display the attributes for a specific product or ALL terms in the attribute taxonomy?  Pretty sure WooCommerce already does the former as `$product->list_attributes()`

Comment: Dear Helga - I'm trying to fetch some product attributes plus the corresponding attribute label and display them in the product short description. The shortcode would be added to a list and should remain the format of the li class. I'm not really an php expert and spent days on this :) You can see the result in this [link](http://www.test.gtoclothing.com/shop/gravity-downhill-t-shirt/)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While I am still not 100% clear what you're after, what I'm going to create is a shortcode that creates a list of all terms in all attributes. To make it more flexible I'll add support for a shortcode parameter so you can create a list of specific attribute terms.

One major thing you need to alter from your code, is that shortcodes need to RETURN a string and not ECHO out html. Echoing out shortcodes can result in unexpected weirdness.

```
/**
 * Attributes shortcode callback.
 */
function so_39394127_attributes_shortcode( $atts ) {

    global $product;

    if( ! is_object( $product ) || ! $product->has_attributes() ){
        return;
    }

    // parse the shortcode attributes
    $args = shortcode_atts( array(
        'attributes' => array_keys( $product->get_attributes() ), // by default show all attributes
    ), $atts );

    // is pass an attributes param, turn into array
    if( is_string( $args['attributes'] ) ){
        $args['attributes'] = array_map( 'trim', explode( '|' , $args['attributes'] ) );
    }

    // start with a null string because shortcodes need to return not echo a value
    $html = '';

    if( ! empty( $args['attributes'] ) ){

        foreach ( $args['attributes'] as $attribute ) {

            // get the WC-standard attribute taxonomy name
            $taxonomy = strpos( $attribute, 'pa_' ) === false ? wc_attribute_taxonomy_name( $attribute ) : $attribute;

            if( taxonomy_is_product_attribute( $taxonomy ) ){

                // Get the attribute label.
                $attribute_label = wc_attribute_label( $taxonomy );

                // Build the html string with the label followed by a clickable list of terms.
                // Updated for WC3.0 to use getters instead of directly accessing property.
                $html .= get_the_term_list( $product->get_id(), $taxonomy, '<li class="bullet-arrow">' . $attribute_label . ': ' , ', ', '</li>' ); 
            }

        }

        // if we have anything to display, wrap it in a <ul> for proper markup
        // OR: delete these lines if you only wish to return the <li> elements
        if( $html ){
            $html = '<ul class="product-attributes">' . $html . '</ul>';
        }

    }

    return $html;
}
add_shortcode( 'display_attributes', 'so_39394127_attributes_shortcode' );
```

**Usage:** This would be used in 1 of 2 ways.

First, to display specific attributes use:

```
[display_attributes attributes="color|material"]
```

Second, to display all attributes use:

```
[display_attributes]
```

**Edit**

Here's an always single display edition:

```
/**
 * Attribute shortcode callback.
 */
function so_39394127_singular_attribute_shortcode( $atts ) {

    global $product;

    if( ! is_object( $product ) || ! $product->has_attributes() ){
        return;
    }

    // parse the shortcode attributes
    $args = shortcode_atts( array(
        'attribute' => ''
    ), $atts );

    // start with a null string because shortcodes need to return not echo a value
    $html = '';

    if( $args['attribute'] ){

        // get the WC-standard attribute taxonomy name
        $taxonomy = strpos( $args['attribute'], 'pa_' ) === false ? wc_attribute_taxonomy_name( $args['attribute'] ) : $args['attribute'];

        if( taxonomy_is_product_attribute( $taxonomy ) ){

            // Get the attribute label.
            $attribute_label = wc_attribute_label( $taxonomy );

            // Build the html string with the label followed by a clickable list of terms.
            // Updated for WC3.0 to use getters instead of directly accessing property.
            $html .= get_the_term_list( $product->get_id(), $taxonomy, $attribute_label . ': ' , ', ', '' );   
        }

    }

    return $html;
}
add_shortcode( 'display_attribute', 'so_39394127_singular_attribute_shortcode' );
```

This removes all HTML markup, and so you'd need to provide your own... which would happen if you are making a custom list.

```
<ul>
    <li class="arrow">Static List Item</li>
    <li class="arrow">[display_attribute attribute="color"]</li>
<ul>
```

**EDIT**: This code can be added to your theme's `functions.php`, but preferably either in a [site-specific plugin](https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/what-why-and-how-tos-of-creating-a-site-specific-wordpress-plugin/) or via the [Code Snippets](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/) plugin.

Comment: Good morning Helga 

Thank you soooo much for your help! It works so far more or less like i want. What i'm not sure is if i need to wrap the following line as we wrap it at the end in a <ul>    

`$html .= get_the_term_list( $product->id, $taxonomy, '<li class="bullet-arrow">' . $attribute_label . ': ' , ', ', '</li>' );`

furthermore i basicaly want to return the string as text, so i can add single attributes by shortcode to an existing and styled <li> element. Like if i have a list with regular text entries and add here and there entries via shortcode.
Hope thats sounds not too weird

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean. If you edit your question with a written out mockup, I can try to advise. I think the shortcode is more broadly usable with the `<ul>` but if you are adding that manually then you maybe don't need it. It's just that if you only have `<li>` tags you have improper markup.

Comment: Hello Helga - ok, i'll try again to explain what i want to achieve: pulling name and value of 1 attribute at time and insert this with the shortcode into a list where i have already other added list entries. So i want to mix static and dynamic content to a list in the product. So far i could not achieve, that if a shortcode is added to a list, it will keep the format (class) of that list. So i do not have to output the shortcode as a list as i will only pull one attribute at a time with the shortcode. Does this make sense? Thank you again and i've spent you a margeritha trough Paypal:)

Comment: I received that, thank you very much!! Cheers! If you are mixing static html with shortcodes, I would suggest you delete the `if( $html ){ $html = '<ul class="product-attributes">' . $html . '</ul>'; }` line. Then you'll only get the `<li>`. It may even make sense to remove the `<li>` from the shortcode so that the shortcode *only* outputs the content, and style the `<li>` in the static html.  See my edited answer for a "singular" alternative.

Comment: WOW! Thank you so much! This did finally what i was aiming for :) I will sure hire you if i'll have some other customizations which i can't do on my own. Greetings from Zürich - Daniel

Comment: @helgatheviking is there a way to not output this as a link ?

Comment: @Jim you could try swapping out `get_the_term_list()` for [`wp_get_object_terms()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_object_terms)

Comment: This is simply amazing @helgatheviking ! Can I ask please is there a way to make it export the attribute values as text only and not links? Thank you in advance !!

Comment: Do you mean output as a list and not links? Export is an entirely different thing. It's `get_the_term_list()` that autogenerates the links. It's definitely possible to rewrite using `get_the_terms()` and a `foreach()` loop instead. You can check the [source of `get_the_terms_list()`](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.0.2/src/wp-includes/category-template.php#L1326-L1366) for ideas.

Comment: @helgatheviking this is wonderful! i am wondering how i could exclude attributes, and also change the order of attributes displayed? if possible other than manually listing those needed in the short-code.

Comment: @vulgarbulgar well `get_the_term_list` doesn't seem to offer any params that would help you. You might have better luck using `wp_get_object_terms()`

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else just wants to simply output the attribute value as text, replace the $html .= line with this:

```
$html .= strip_tags(get_the_term_list($product->get_id(), $taxonomy));
```

@helgatheviking There must be a more elegant way than this! :)

Answer (score 1):

Needed this recently - found https://wordpress.org/plugins/wcpas-product-attributes-shortcode/ does the trick.

With this plugin you can set an "attribute" parameter to match one of the product attributes you have setup.

For example if you have a brand attribute you can use:

`[wcpas_product_attributes attribute="brand"]`

This will output a `<ul>` list containing all brands.

There are also a number of parameters you can use alongside the attribute including:

- orderby (order the list by an orderby value)
- order (order asc, desc, rand, etc)
- hide_empty (hide empty terms)
- show_counts (show the total number of products in the brand)
- archive_links (use an archive based URL instead of a filter based URL)
- min_price (When using archive_links = 0 you can have a price filter based URL off a minimum price)
- max_price (When using archive_links = 0 you can have a price filter based URL off a maximum price)

Comment: Please don't just post some tool / package or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Answer (score 1):

The old codes wasn't working for me, so here is the updated code:

```
[display_attribute_terms attribute="SLUG"]
```

Add any one of the below code snippet in your theme's functions.php OR in a [site-specific plugin](https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/what-why-and-how-tos-of-creating-a-site-specific-wordpress-plugin/) OR via [Code Snippets](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/) plugin.

```
function display_attribute_terms_shortcode( $atts ) {
    $args = shortcode_atts( array(
        'attribute' => '',
    ), $atts );
    if ( empty( $args['attribute'] ) ) {
        return '';
    }
    $taxonomy = strpos( $args['attribute'], 'pa_' ) === false ? wc_attribute_taxonomy_name( $args['attribute'] ) : $args['attribute'];
    if ( ! taxonomy_exists( $taxonomy ) ) {
        return '';
    }
    $terms = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy'   => $taxonomy,
        'hide_empty' => false,
    ) );
    if ( is_wp_error( $terms ) || empty( $terms ) ) {
        return '';
    }
    $html = '<ul class="attribute-terms-list">';
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $html .= sprintf(
            '<li><a href="%s">%s</a></li>',
            esc_url( get_term_link( $term, $taxonomy ) ),
            esc_html( $term->name )
        );
    }
    $html .= '</ul>';
    return $html;
}add_shortcode( 'display_attribute_terms', 'display_attribute_terms_shortcode' );
```

And here is another code if you want to display description next to your attribute terms.

```
function display_attribute_terms_shortcode( $atts ) {
    $args = shortcode_atts( array(
        'attribute' => '',
    ), $atts );
    if ( empty( $args['attribute'] ) ) {
        return '';
    }
    $taxonomy = strpos( $args['attribute'], 'pa_' ) === false ? wc_attribute_taxonomy_name( $args['attribute'] ) : $args['attribute'];

    if ( ! taxonomy_exists( $taxonomy ) ) {
        return '';
    }
    $terms = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy'   => $taxonomy,
        'hide_empty' => false,
    ) );
    if ( is_wp_error( $terms ) || empty( $terms ) ) {
        return '';
    }
    $html = '<ul class="attribute-terms-list">';
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $term_description = ! empty( $term->description ) ? '<span class="term-description">' . esc_html( $term->description ) . '</span>' : '';
        $html .= sprintf(
            '<li><a href="%s">%s</a> %s</li>',
            esc_url( get_term_link( $term, $taxonomy ) ),
            esc_html( $term->name ),
            $term_description
        );
    }
    $html .= '</ul>';
    return $html;
}add_shortcode( 'display_attribute_terms', 'display_attribute_terms_shortcode' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another.. https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-product-shortcodes/

Makes things pretty simple