# Wordpress woocommerce product attribute labe - remove "product"

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I think this must be pretty simple, but I am struggling to find the file to edit in Woocommerce to remove "product" before the attribute label output.

My example here is for vehicles. I'd rather it didn't say "product year", but just "year":

```
Product Year: 2014
Product Transmission: Automatic
Product Fuel: Diesel
Product Air Conditioning: Yes
Product Axles: 6x2
```

Can anyone help me to identify the source of the word "product" in order to remove it?
i'm on WP 4.8 & WooCom 3.0.9
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing exactly where your label is being outputted it's hard to know what to edit, but I did find from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39400741/) that if you access the label like this:

```
$attribute_label = $taxonomy_object->labels->name;
```

you return the label including "product" eg `"Product Year"`, but if you access it like this:

```
 $attribute_label = wc_attribute_label( $taxonomy );
```

you only get the attribute eg `"Year"`