# Woocommerce - Show and sort attributes in code

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes

I have found this coding on here for showing WooCommerce product attributes on a product page: [Woocommerce - Display single product attribute(s) with shortcodes in Frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39394127/woocommerce-display-single-product-attributes-with-shortcodes-in-frontend#_=)_

I know there are ways of gettting the attributes sorted within the WooCommerce backend, but I cannot get them to work like they should. I see a lot of people have issues with the sorting of attributes. Is there a way to make them sort by "slug" by modifying this code?

```
/**
 * Attributes shortcode callback.
 */
function so_39394127_attributes_shortcode( $atts ) {

    global $product;

    if( ! is_object( $product ) || ! $product->has_attributes() ){
        return;
    }

    // parse the shortcode attributes
    $args = shortcode_atts( array(
        'attributes' => array_keys( $product->get_attributes() ), // by default show all attributes
    ), $atts );

    // is pass an attributes param, turn into array
    if( is_string( $args['attributes'] ) ){
        $args['attributes'] = array_map( 'trim', explode( '|' , $args['attributes'] ) );
    }

    // start with a null string because shortcodes need to return not echo a value
    $html = '';

    if( ! empty( $args['attributes'] ) ){

        foreach ( $args['attributes'] as $attribute ) {

            // get the WC-standard attribute taxonomy name
            $taxonomy = strpos( $attribute, 'pa_' ) === false ? wc_attribute_taxonomy_name( $attribute ) : $attribute;

            if( taxonomy_is_product_attribute( $taxonomy ) ){

                // Get the attribute label.
                $attribute_label = wc_attribute_label( $taxonomy );

                // Build the html string with the label followed by a clickable list of terms.
                // Updated for WC3.0 to use getters instead of directly accessing property.
                $html .= get_the_term_list( $product->get_id(), $taxonomy, '<li class="bullet-arrow">' . $attribute_label . ': ' , ', ', '</li>' ); 
            }

        }

        // if we have anything to display, wrap it in a <ul> for proper markup
        // OR: delete these lines if you only wish to return the <li> elements
        if( $html ){
            $html = '<ul class="product-attributes">' . $html . '</ul>';
        }

    }

    return $html;
}
add_shortcode( 'display_attributes', 'so_39394127_attributes_shortcode' );
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone were still looking for the answer, if you add

```
sort($args['attributes']);
```

before the foreach loop, it will sort the attributes displayed by the attribute slug