# Woocommerce - Dynamically display attribute value as anchor text with another attribute value as the href link (with shortcodes)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-shortcode

I am creating a product page template and I want to display a text link that has the top-level URL (externalwebsite.com) as the anchor text and then the specific product page (externalwebsite.com/product) as the href attribute.

I imagine the html of the output to look something like this:

```
<a href="$product_url_attribute">$brand_url_attribute</a>
```

I am using the solution by [@helgatheviking](https://stackoverflow.com/users/383847/helgatheviking) on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39394127/woocommerce-display-single-product-attributes-with-shortcodes-in-frontend) to pull and display individual attributes using shortcodes and it works really well for my needs.

I've tried messing around with this code to achieve what I need, but the PHP is a little too over my head.

Let me know if I haven't been clear.

I appreciate all the help on this.

Answer (score 0):

So, I managed to achieve the desired result, even if it is a bit clunky.

I just used an HTML block and wrote out the HTML and inserted the shortcodes into their respective places.

```
<p>View on <a href="[display_attributes attributes='product-url']">[display_attributes attributes="brand-website"]</a></p>
```

I also had to make sure I changed the double quotes in the shortcode to single quotes to ensure the href attribute didn't close early.

If you know a more eloquent way to do this, please let me know.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).